# Duplicate sheets with buttons

Tags: excel, vba, button, duplicates

I currently have a single worksheet with 3 buttons that all run a subroutine if clicked. I have written another subroutine that copies the current sheet and pastes all the data into a new worksheet. The code is as follow:

```
Public Sub DuplicateSheet()
      ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
      On Error Resume Next
      ActiveSheet.Name = "Test Sheet"
End Sub
```

However, the new sheet only contains the data but not the buttons. How do I duplicate the buttons with the subroutines still assigned?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel Options >> Advanced section >> Cut, Copy and Sort inserted objects with their parent cells

or in VBA set

```
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True
```

Comment: Great answer! When set to true, I was able to copy Form Controls, ActiveX Controls and AutoShapes. When set to false, none of those were copied to the new sheet. It was true by default on my application.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!! much better than the other answer i got.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer:

```
      ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(488, 171, 120, 30).Select
      Selection.OnAction = "name of subroutine"
```